# charArray failed to return value

Tags: c#

I am having a problem with Take() below. It returned this

> Error 4   'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Take' and no
>   extension method 'Take' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)
>
> return mm.Take(9).ToArray();

```
public char[] Find(string str)
        {
            char[] mm = new char[str.Length];
            int idx = 0;
            foreach (char k in str)
            {
                if ((k >= '0' && k <= '9'))
                {
                    mm[idx] = k;
                    idx++;
                }
            }
            return mm.Take(9).ToArray();
        }
```

Comment: Have you included the proper `using` directives to use the `Take` extension method, then?

Comment: Add `using System.Linq;` to fix this problem. Voting to close as "cannot reproduce" ([demo](http://ideone.com/lJfxQa)).

Answer (score 2):

You need to Add `using System.Linq;` to your class so `Take` became available method.